# How do I manually register Mediatr handlers, in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mediatr

I'm using ASP.NET Core, with the built-in container.

Automatic registration is supposed to be done [like so](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/07/19/mediatr-extensions-for-microsoft-dependency-injection-released/):

```
services.AddMvc();
services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup));
```

This automatically 1) configures MediatR, and 2) registers all handlers found in the assembly.

But I want to register my handlers manually. How do I do that?

Answer (score 10):

Today I had a same issue, instead of using extension to scan assemblies and add all handlers automatically. We have a need to register it manually.

Here is working example how it should be register:

```cs
var serviceConfig = new MediatRServiceConfiguration();
ServiceRegistrar.AddRequiredServices(services, serviceConfig);
services.AddScoped<IRequestHandler<MyCommand, MyCommandResponse>, MyCommandHandler>();
```

Where `MediarRServiceConfiguration` is from `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` and `ServiceRegistrar` from `MediatR.Registration`

Answer (score 2):

```cs
services.AddTransient<IRequestHandler<MyRequestModel, MyResponseModel>, MyHandler>();
```